# Java: Size of each character in a String

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I have read at various places on the web that Java internally uses UTF-16 to represent String objects. This means that each character in a String takes two bytes. However for the following code we find that each of the characters may take variable number of bytes in a String.

```
public class ChracterSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\u0061\u024E\u2013\u65E5";
        System.out.println(s + " " + s.getBytes().length);

        System.out.println("\u0061" + " " + "\u0061".getBytes().length);
        System.out.println("\u024E" + " " + "\u024E".getBytes().length);
        System.out.println("\u2013" + " " + "\u2013".getBytes().length);
        System.out.println("\u65E5" + " " + "\u65E5".getBytes().length);

    }

}
```

Output of above program is:

```
aɎ–日 9
a 1
Ɏ 2
– 3
日 3
```

Corresponding code points for each of the characters are:

```
a : \u0061
Ɏ : \u024E
– : \u2013
日 : \u65E5
```

What is the explanation for this behavior?

I have to store text, which may contain non-Roman characters, into a fixed byte length field in the database. Should I assume that I should allocate four times the length of text to be on safe side?

Comment: The explanation is in the duplicate, as for your problem: why are you storing text in a byte field? You could also sanitize the input to make sure that surrogate pairs or any other data isn't inserted.

Comment: > why are you storing text in a byte field?
I am not. I am using getBytes() to find out amount of space taken by each character.

Comment: Sure you are: "into a fixed byte length field in the database". I would use a flexible length text field in the database, with a proper encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getBytes()` doesn't give you the number of bytes stored in the string. Rather, it gives you the bytes that represent this string in a particular encoding, in this case, the default encoding, which is probably UTF-8.

Internally, the string holds an array of the type `char`, and that type holds exactly two bytes per item. However, some supplementary characters may be represented by two array entries, so they might actually take 4 bytes inside the string.

Comment: As mentioned by @Kayaman 's duplicate, it should be UTF-16.

Comment: RealSkeptic is right about the encoding, you need to use `getBytes("UTF-16")` to get the bytes required for UCS-2 encoding. However even then a character can take more than 2 bytes as explained in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-16 does not mean every character is encoded on 2 bytes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

> UTF-16 (16-bit Unicode Transformation Format) is a character encoding
>   capable of encoding all 1,112,064 possible characters in Unicode. The
>   encoding is variable-length, as code points are encoded with one or
>   two 16-bit code units. (also see Comparison of Unicode encodings for a
>   comparison of UTF-8, -16 & -32)
>
> UTF-16 developed from an earlier fixed-width 16-bit encoding known as
>   UCS-2 (for 2-byte Universal Character Set) once it became clear that a
>   fixed-width 2-byte encoding could not encode enough characters to be
>   truly universal.

Comment: How does that explain that some characters take 3 bytes only.